# Isomorphism between $R=\{ a+ b\sqrt{2} : a,b \in \mathbb Q \}$ and $\mathbb Q[x]/(f)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I am reading a syllabus about Discrete Mathematics. One of the problems encouraged in the syllabus to solve is the following.

Define $R= \{ a+ b\sqrt{2} : a,b \in \mathbb Q \}$ Find $f$ so $f$ defines an isomorphism between R and $\mathbb Q[x]/(f)$. Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: I would consider the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}$, do you know what this means?

Comment: I know what minimal polynomials are in the context of finite fields. With minimal polynomial do you mean the polynomial of lowest degree that makes $\sqrt{2}$ zero? Don't really see the connection between minimal polynomials and this problem.

Answer (score 3):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$The idea is to consider the unique ring homomoprphism
$$
\phi : \mathbb{Q}[x] \to R
$$
which satisfies $\phi(a) = a$ for $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $\phi(x) = \sqrt{2}$.

Show this is surjective, and find that the kernel is the principal ideal generated by the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

This assumes a bit of knowledge. It can be reformulated in more elementary terms, though. Please advise in case.